# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry in Symfony 4

Tags: php, database, symfony, error-handling, doctrine

I have a table named 'student_assignment' in which I have multiple columns from which I am showing 2 of them below:

Both of these columns are also foreign keys.

```
StudentId   assignmentId
    1           6          -> allowed
    2           3          -> allowed
    3           1          -> allowed
    2           3          -> not allowed, the combination of 2 3 already exists in table.
```

I have made combination of these two columns successfully.

I am using multiple select to assign a assignment say '**Assignment no 3**' to multiple students. Those students already have **Assignment 3** cant be reassigned. 
When I reassign '**Assigment 3**' twice a student then it throws me error:

Error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '2-3' for key 'assignment_unique'

I want a solution in which those student who does not have Assignment no 3 can be assigned and those who have these assigment should be ignored.

Comment: Take a look at UniqueEntity constraint [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

Comment: @Shady: I have but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: What problem did you have when you looked at that thing, @Saurabh?

Answer (score 0):

As @Shady said in comments, you should use UniqueEntity constraint. You can use this on multiple fields and combinations. For example, in your case you should use it like this:

```
<constraint name="Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity">
    <option name="fields">
        <value>fieldOne</value>
        <value>fieldTwo</value>
    </option>
</constraint>
```

Note: First field will show the errors, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you fetch those data from database as *ArrayCollection* object. I suggest you to make sure that 2 is not associated with 2 before add them in your database. If not possible, I suggest to review your model (relations between yours entities).